# c++11 capture-by-value lambda producing wrong value

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to store a lambda in an object system involving several layers of indirection. I'm using g++ 4.7.1.

Depending on how exactly I construct the (equivalent) objects, the lambda may or may not have the correct value.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional> // used for std::function

using namespace std; // TODO nope

typedef function<int()> intf;


struct SaveLambda {
    const intf func;
    SaveLambda(const intf& _func) : func(_func) {}  
};


struct StoreSaved {
    const SaveLambda* child;
    StoreSaved(const SaveLambda& _child) : child(&_child) {
        cout << "Before returning parent: " <<  child->func() << endl;
    }
};


int main() {
    const int ten = 10;

    auto S = SaveLambda([ten](){return ten;});
    cout << "No indirection: " << S.func() << endl << endl;

    auto saved = StoreSaved(S);
    cout << "Indirection, saved: " << saved.child->func() << endl << endl;

    auto temps = StoreSaved ( SaveLambda([ten](){cout << "&ten: "<< &ten << endl; return ten;}) );
    cout << "***** what. *****" << endl;
    cout << "Indirection, unsaved: " << temps.child->func() << endl;
    cout << "***** what. *****" << endl << endl;

    cout << "ten still lives: " << ten << endl;
}
```

Compile as `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o itest itest.cpp` and run: notice the one line of output with a different value.

What am I doing wrong? I assumed that capture-by-value would, well, capture by value. (Observe most disconcertingly that the print in StoreSaved (line 15) produces the *correct* value, unlike line 34, despite these both referring to the same object. The only difference is adding another layer of indirection.)

Comment: You want to make a copy of the saved lambda and not keep a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
auto temps = StoreSaved(
                /* This temporary value dies at the last semicolon! */
                SaveLambda([ten](){cout << "&ten: "<< &ten << endl; return ten;})
                );
```

`StoreSaved` then has a pointer to a nonexistent object. Using it is UB.

Comment: Hm. I assumed it would be copied - is there some reason it isn't? (Changing StorSaved from call-by-const-reference to call-by-value doesn't change the behavior, incidentally.) It was my impression that call-by-value, at least, would save temporaries, even temporary objects.

Comment: @Bakkot:  It's not the lambda capture, it's your StoreSaved, which is capturing by pointer.

Comment: @Bakkot: I'm not sure I follow. Copy what to where? And yes, changing const-reference to value just changes the scope of the value (the latter having an even smaller scope), the problem remains.

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out by others, the problem is that in `temps` you end with a pointer to a nonexistent `SaveLambda` struct, as it is a temporary.

You can keep a copy using a SaveLambda struct in StoreSaved, instead of a pointer:

```
struct StoreSaved {
   const SaveLambda child;
   StoreSaved(const SaveLambda& _child) : child(_child) {
       cout << "Before returning parent: " <<  child.func() << endl;
   }
};
```

You also have to change all the `child->func()` to `child.func()`, as you are not dealing with a pointer anymore.